# Write LINQ query without select or group clause using extension method syntax

Tags: c#, linq

I'm writing a function that builds a query based on a condition. What I want to do is have a different `select` statements for each condition (the query in a separate method, then each user can have his\her own select statements).

Kinda like this

```
var q = BuildQuery();
var nq = q.Select(...);
return nq.ToList();
```

Will write a query using extension method syntax solves the ' a query body must end with a select or group clause'.

Here's my query

```
        return (from ScheduleItemAttendee SIA in context.ScheduleItemAttendees
               join AttendeeService AS in context.AttendeeServices on SIA.Id equals AS.AttendeeId into x
               from Att in x.DefaultIfEmpty()
               where (Att == null || !Att.IsDeleted)
               && !(SIA == null || SIA.IsDeleted)

               && ((string.IsNullOrEmpty(criteria.Keyword)) || (SIA.Individual.FullNameAr.Trim().ToLower().Contains(criteria.Keyword) || SIA.Individual.FullNameEn.Trim().ToLower().Contains(criteria.Keyword))));
```

Comment: Then provide a `Func<ScheduleItemAttendee, AttendeeService, T> selector` as a parameter to a generic method with a generic parameter `T`. Then you use `select selector(SIA, Att)` in your method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
public IQueryable<T> BuildQuery<T>(Expression<Func<ScheduleItemAttendee, AttendeeService, T>> selector)
{
    return
        from ScheduleItemAttendee SIA in context.ScheduleItemAttendees
        join AttendeeService AS in context.AttendeeServices on SIA.Id equals AS.AttendeeId into x
        from Att in x.DefaultIfEmpty()
        where (Att == null || !Att.IsDeleted)
            && !(SIA == null || SIA.IsDeleted)
            && ((string.IsNullOrEmpty(criteria.Keyword))
                || (SIA.Individual.FullNameAr.Trim().ToLower().Contains(criteria.Keyword)
                || SIA.Individual.FullNameEn.Trim().ToLower().Contains(criteria.Keyword)))
        select selector(SIA, null);
}
```

Then use it like this:

```
var q = BuildQuery((sia, att) => 42);
```

(Put something meaningful in the place of `42`.)

Comment: Sorry, the return should have been `IQueryable<T>` rather than `T`.

Comment: This is going to query all columns from ScheduleItemAttendee (and maybe AttendeeService) and then the selector is applied locally. This is quite wasteful.

Comment: @AntonínLejsek - No, it doesn't do that. It'll only select the columns defined in `selector`.

Comment: It does query all columns, I tried it. And it makes sense as selector is ordinary Func (not Expression) and can be absolutely anything.

Comment: @AntonínLejsek - Ah, sorry, I edited the code and accidentally removed the `Expression`. My first edit of this answer had it. I'll pop it back in.

Comment: Strange thing is it does not get compiled this way, query syntax seems to be too limited for this.